# JavaScript event - mouseover attached to SVG rectangles, partially failed to response

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, dom-events

The following is using `create-react-app` created the boilerplate and rendered the only component is `TestComponent`. In `TestComponent` it rendered a SVG showing a few rectangles. ([screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2U3C.png)).

The `mouseover` event is attached to the SVG rect. My expectation is once I move mouse cross the rect, the console will print the log of the mouse position - (`clientX`, `clientY`).

The behaviour worked on most of the rectangles but not all of them.
The following rectangles are working:

- 1st, 2nd, 5th, 6th, 7th vertical rectangle

The `3rd and 4th` vertical rectangle not print `clientX` and `clientY`.

[image: svg rectangles]

[image: not working on red]
[image: console log]

To ensure there is no overlay among these rectangles, I have removed all the horizontal rectangles. And the mouseover events are the same things, the third and the fourth vertical rectangles mouseover events not working.

[image]

I am keen to believe this is a brower bug but I am not sure. The reason is if I change the stoke-width to 20px, the third and fourth rectangle responsed to the mouseover event. However, if the strike-width is 1px, no matter how many times I move across these two rectangles, it has no response at all.

I am using the latest Chrome browser - Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image]

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import TestComponent from "./components/test.jsx";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <TestComponent />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  root
);
reportWebVitals();
```

`test.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  onRectMouseOver = (e) => {
    console.log(`${e.clientX} ${e.clientY}`);
  };
  render() {
    const rects = JSON.parse(
      "[[0, 45, 45, 2370], [1955, 45, 45, 2370], [355, 45, 45, 2370], [710, 45, 45, 2370], [1065, 45, 45, 2370], [1420, 45, 45, 2370], [1775, 45, 45, 2370], [45, 845, 310.0, 45], [45, 1645, 310.0, 45], [400, 845, 310.0, 45], [400, 1645, 310.0, 45], [755, 845, 310.0, 45], [755, 1645, 310.0, 45], [1110, 845, 310.0, 45], [1110, 1645, 310.0, 45], [1465, 845, 310.0, 45], [1465, 1645, 310.0, 45], [1820, 845, 135.0, 45], [1820, 1645, 135.0, 45], [0, 2415, 2000, 45], [0, 0, 2000, 45]]"
    );

    return (
      <div style={{ width: 5000, height: 3000, backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
        <svg
          viewBox="0 0 5000 3000"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          transform="scale(1,-1)"
        >
          <g>
            {rects &&
              rects.map((rect, index) => {
                let [x, y, width, height] = rect;

                return (
                  <rect
                    x={x}
                    y={y}
                    width={width}
                    height={height}
                    key={index}
                    style={{ fill: "None", strokeWidth: 1, stroke: "black" }}
                    onMouseOver={(e) => {
                      this.onRectMouseOver(e);
                    }}
                  >
                    <title>
                      x: {x}; y: {x}; width: {width}; height:
                      {height}
                    </title>
                  </rect>
                );
              })}
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did check the Z axis, there is no second layer on the path of my mouse when I move the mouse over the third and fourth vertical rectangle @RobertLongson

Comment: I've used the  const rects in your code to generate the svg. The result is different from the image in your question. Also the `viewBox="0 0 5000 3000"` is unapropiate fir the svg you have. Are you using the right code?

Comment: I used the same size viewBox with div so the ratio is 1:1. Transom is used also@enxaneta . The version of code is corresponding to the screenshot. The code is “right” in terms of screenshot but it’s not correct regarding the mouseover event.

Comment: @RobertLongson Removed all the horizontal rectangles so as to no overlay among these rectangles. The result is the same.

Comment: @RobertLongson @enxaneta I am very keen to believe this is a Chrome bug. I have raised this issue to Chrome Develop team via Chrome `report an issue`.

Comment: `fill: None` makes it difficult to click, but it should be clickable. How about `fill: transparent`?

Comment: @qrsngky It works!!!
I tried with `fill: transparent`. Now every edges of each rectangles respond to the `mouseover` event. 

Do you consider put it below as an answer? I will accept it as an answer if you do so.

Comment: adjusting the pointer-events property should be more efficient than fill: transparent.

Comment: @cdhit note that `fill: transparent` means that moving over the interior of the rectangles will trigger events. I don't know your exact purpose, but I also thought it may feel odd that only the borders are sensitive ― it can be very difficult to exactly touch the borders if you have stroke-width =1 and zoom < 100% (fill: none means only borders are actually considered part of the shape;  the interiors are empty and won't receive events)

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks I didn't know it. I find it a bit odd, though, as I thought there should be no fill at all to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were using `fill: none` (and the default value of pointer-events property), only the borders will ever trigger an event, and not the interior. And each of your rectangles has very narrow strokes, only 1px wide (might occupy 2px because of "1px border blur"*), so if you move very fast, it's possible to skip more than just 3rd and 4th rectangles (in fact it's not that hard to skip most of the rectangles).

You can see how easy it is to miss the rectangles, e.g. try to use right-click and inspect, or use "Select an element (Ctrl+Shift+C)" of in the Chrome DevTools.

I can reproduce the effect on Firefox as well, by moving the mouse very fast (not limited to 3rd or 4th rectangles).

(*by "1px border blur", I mean, e.g. the 3B of https://vecta.io/blog/5-most-common-problems-faced-by-svg-users 3B. And there is a similar problem with canvas: https://usefulangle.com/post/17/html5-canvas-drawing-1px-crisp-straight-lines )

Also, just using Chrome, I managed to trigger your third and the fourth vertical rectangles simply by using super-slow horizontal movements of the mouse.
So, I guess the actual problem is that your mouse pointer can move more than 2px per unit of time, so it's easy to "jump" over the border without triggering anything.
I think the browsers worked as they should.

**Work around 1:**
One possible work around is by using `fill: transparent` (which is the same as `fill: rgba(0,0,0,0)`), so the interior can trigger mouse events. Then it's not that easy to miss a rectangle.
(There may be side effects, though, since the sensitive areas are larger now).

[edit: one side effect is that the rendering is more expensive, as it would have to paint over the interior, and then the "opacity" means that you calculate the result by combining the colors of current object and the colors of the background, even though it has no visible effect due to 0 opacity (i.e. output is the same as just background)]

**Work around 2:** Change pointer-events css property.
Here `pointer-events: fill` works even though the fill is none
(I used to wonder if it was intentional, as I thought with `fill: none` there should be not any 'fill' to trigger any pointer event. But I found from the description in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events that it's intentional) 
And it works both with Chrome and Firefox.
You may also change it to `pointer-events: visible` if you also want the border to trigger events (instead of just the interior), but then there is not much difference when your borders are very thin.
(There is also `pointer-events: all` but then it may be surprising when visibility is hidden)

Comment: Work around 2 is actually the right answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I wonder, what is the difference in practice? The event listener has to do something within those areas, too. Is it that the rendering becomes more expensive with fill:transparent?

Comment: it's the latter, rendering is more expensive.

Comment: I can' agree this - `Since you were using fill: none (and the default value of pointer-events property), only the borders will ever trigger an event, and not the interior. And each of your rectangles has very narrow strokes, ...`

This is not about how quickly I moved mouse over the third and fourth verticle rectangle. Actually the result is no matter how slow or how many times I moved my mouse over, it just didn't work when `fill: 'None'`

Comment: @chdit In that case, that means I can't reproduce your effect. Maybe your Chrome browser is special, while my Chrome browser is normal, who knows? Now I'm not even sure if "work around 2" would even work for your case. Or is it because of zoom level? Maybe it's floating point arithmetic again? For the record, I used 100% zoom and didn't try other zoom levels.

Comment: @qrsngky This `fill: transparent` is very helpful. I am sorry about the issue is not reproduced in your your environment. However, the answer is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am keen to believe this is a Chrome broswer bug.

It is working on Firefox - 103.0.2 (64-bit).